# Coherent sheaves of finite length over $\mathbb{P}^n_k$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, sheaf-theory

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. Are there any *nonzero* coherent sheaves on the projective space $\mathbb{P}^n_k$ that are supported at (only) *finitely many* closed points? If they don't exist, what is the reason?

Comment: Sure, skyscraper sheaves ...

Comment: But are skyscraper sheaves coherent?

Comment: In general, if $i : Z \to X$ is a closed immersion of noetherian schemes, and $F \in \mathrm{Coh}(Z)$, then $i_* F \in \mathrm{Coh}(X)$. One simply reduces to the observation that $\mathcal{O}_X/I$ is coherent if $I$ defines $i$. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I am confused by the answer provided to this question:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/642262/is-skyscraper-sheaf-quasi-coherent

Comment: There is no reason to be confused: there exist non-coherent skyscraper sheaves and I have described one in the answer you link to. But Martin gives and justifie a perfectly correct recipe for the construction of coherent skyscraper sheaves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So let me make my comment to an answer (just to take this question off the list of unanswered ones):

If $i : Z \to X$ is a closed immersion and $M$ is a quasi-coherent module on $Z$ of finite type, then also $i_* M$ is a quasi-coherent module on $X$ of finite type. For noetherian schemes, finite type = coherent. Now let $x \in X$ be a closed point and $i : \mathrm{Spec} k(x) \to X$ the corresponding inclusion. Then $i_* \mathcal{O}_{k(x)}$ is a quasi-coherent module of finite type on $X$, which is supported at $\{x\}$. This is a skyscraper sheaf.