# Why isn't every $\mathcal O_X$-module quasi-coherent?

Tags: modules, sheaf-theory, quasicoherent-sheaves

This might be a stupid question, but I don't understand an easy fact. Let $(X,\mathcal O_X)$ a ringed space.

We know that **every** module $M$ over a ring $R$ has a free presentation, so why isn't every $\mathcal O_X$-module quasi-coherent?

Why doesn't the free presentation:
 $\mathcal O_X^{(J)}|_U\rightarrow\mathcal O_X^{(I)}|_U\rightarrow\mathcal F|_U\rightarrow 0$
 exist in general?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: A counterexample is given here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/642262/is-skyscraper-sheaf-quasi-coherent

Comment: Ok, counterexamples exist. But I'd like to know what goes wrong in general

Comment: Maybe the problem is that the indexes $I$ and $J$ should be fixed for the whole open set $U$.

Comment: The problem is that locally on $U = Spec (A)$, $\mathcal {F}|_{U}$ is not a sheaf given by a module $M$ over $A$. Certainly $\mathcal{F} (U)$ is a module over $A$, but  $\mathcal {F}|_{U} (D(f)) \cong M_f$ may *not* hold

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) You write "We know that **every** module $M$ over a ring $R$ has a free presentation, so why isn't every $\mathcal O_X$-module quasi-coherent?
"
But this is begging the question: the correspondence on affine schemes between sheaves and their modules of sections is only valid for quasi-coherent sheaves!

2) Given an  arbitrary $\mathcal O_X$- module and a point $x\in X$, there need not even exist a neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ and  a surjective morphism of sheaves $\mathcal O_X^{(I)}|U\rightarrow\mathcal F|U\rightarrow 0$.
Indeed, from the Stacks Project (section 17.8) we can extract the following
**Example:**
Let $X=\mathbb R$ with the usual topology, endowed with the constant sheaf   $\mathcal O_X=\underline{\mathbb Z}$ to make it a ringed space.
Let $U =\mathbb R^*_+\subset X$ be the open subspace of positive numbers and let $\mathcal  Z=\mathcal O_X\mid U$ be the constant sheaf associated to $\mathbb Z$ on $U$.
Now if $i:U\hookrightarrow \mathbb R$ is the inclusion, consider  the sheaf  $\mathcal F:=i_!\mathcal Z$ on $X$.
For  any connected neighbourhood $U$ of $0$ in X we have $\Gamma(U,\mathcal F)=0$ so that there can be no surjection $\mathcal O _X^{(I)}\mid U\to \mathcal F\mid U\to 0$.
[Recall that morphisms  $\mathcal O _X^{(I)}\mid U\to \mathcal F\mid U$ correspond to families $(s_i)$ of sections $s_i\in \Gamma(U,\mathcal F)$]

Comment: Why does the $0$ map not work at the end?

Answer (score 2):

You can always get an exact sequence
$ \mathcal{O}_X(U)^I\to \mathcal{O}_X(U)^J\to \mathcal{F}(U)\to 0$, but it is not guaranteed that you can get it to behave well with respect to the restriction maps.

The definition of quasi-coherence you gave is equivalent to the following (which is really helpful to understand):
Let $U=Spec(A)$ be an affine open subset of $X$, and let $f\in A$ be a function on $U$. Then the restriction map $\mathcal{F}(U)\to \mathcal{F}(U_f)$ is exactly the localisation of $\mathcal{F}(U)$ with respect to $f$.

Now you should see that this is a non-trivial requirement, and does not follow from the sheaf axiom.

Comment: Your exact sequence confuses sheaves and their sections.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, every $R$-module has a free presentation; and the proof of this fact is constructive, hence also applies in sheaf toposes (by their "internal language"). Run there, it shows that every sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules has a free presentation
$$ \mathcal{O}_X\langle \mathcal{A} \rangle \to
\mathcal{O}_X\langle \mathcal{B} \rangle \to
\mathcal{O}_X\langle \mathcal{F} \rangle \to 0, $$
where $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ are certain sheaves of sets.

But the condition for a sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules to be quasicoherent is much stronger: For that, there needs to be a presentation as above where $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ are locally constant.