# Sheaf of sections supported at a point is coherent?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a coherent analytic sheaf over some open subset of $U ⊆ \mathbb{C}^n$. I read in a book that if $p \in U$ then the subsheaf $\mathcal{G}$ defined by
\begin{equation}
 \mathcal{G}(V) = \left\{s \in \mathcal{F} ~\middle|~ s|_{V ∖ \{p\}} = 0\right\}
\end{equation}
is a **coherent** subsheaf. How can you see this?

**One idea:** It is my understanding that "finite-dimensional skyscrapers" supported at a point are coherent.
That is, you have a $\mathcal{O}_p$-module $M$ that is finite-dimensional as a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space and you consider the sheaf
\begin{equation}
 V \mapsto \begin{cases}
  M & p \in V \\ 0 & p \not\in V
 \end{cases}
\end{equation}
So it would be sufficient to check that $\mathcal{G}_p$ is finite-dimensional. For this I think it would suffice to show that $\mathfrak{m}^k \mathcal{G}_p = 0$ for sufficiently large $k$.

Answer (score 1):

your understanding is right, skyscrapers of finite dimensional vector spaces are coherent! That is, if you define skyscraper sheaves to be coherent in the first place (see also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/642262/is-skyscraper-sheaf-quasi-coherent)).

Generally you should think of a coherent skyscraper sheaf as a finitely generated $\mathcal{O}_{X,p}$-module $\mathbf{M}$ over a point $i: \{p\} \hookrightarrow X$ and you get the coherent sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_X$- modules on $X$ by considering $
i_*\mathbf{M}$ on $X$.
Check that $\mathcal{G}_q = 0$ if $q \neq p$. Indeed, $\mathcal{G}_q = \underset{\longrightarrow}\lim \mathcal{G}(V)$ where $V$ ranges over opens in $U$ containing $q$. Now if $q$ and $p$ are distinct then you can always find opens $V$ not containing $p$, hence $\mathcal{G}(V)\equiv 0 $ there after passing to the limit, so $\mathcal{G}_q = 0$ for $q\neq p$.

Now $\mathcal{G}_p$ is a $\mathbf{C}$-subspace of $H^0(\mathcal{F}_p)=Hom(\mathcal{O}_p,\mathcal{F}_p)\cong Hom(\mathcal{O}_X,i_*A)$ where $A$ is the $\mathcal{O}_p$-module $\mathcal{F}_p$ seen as a skyscraper sheaf over $p$ which is again coherent hence has finite dimensional global sections over a point.
The last equality uses that talking stalks and skyscrapers are adjoint.

**Edit**: Concerning the confusion regarding $\mathcal{F}_p$: $\mathcal{F_p}/({\mathcal{F}_p}m_p)$ is finite dimensional vector space and any basis lifts to a minimal generating set of $\mathcal{F}_p$ (that is Nakayamas lemma) which are precisely the elements of $H^0(\mathcal{F}_p)$.

Comment: Certainly you need the scyscraper to be a finite-dimensional $\mathbb{C}$-vector space, otherwise you contradict finiteness theorems for $H^0$.

Comment: ok I don't understand your remark and your downvote: I said its finite dimensional? Please correct my if I'm wrong but finiteness for $H^0$ is a property of projective varieties?

Comment: how do you know that the $\mathcal{G}_p$ is finite−dimensional?

Comment: also there is no projective variety in the question. (And the sheaves are analytic although that probably makes no difference?)

Comment: it makes no difference over proper spaces. So affine spaces excluded. But I think you only need coherence over a point if I'm not mistaken

Comment: I edited the answer concerning the other question

Comment: Exactly, just the inclusion.

Comment: What is your last paragraph arguing? That $\mathcal{G}_p$ is finite-dimensional? (I don't see how that would follow, given that $\mathcal{F}_p$ doesn't have to be)

Comment: $\mathcal{F}_p$ is finite! Its a coherent sheaf over a point (which is projective if you prefer to see it that way)

Comment: I'm confused. By $\mathcal{F}_p$ don't you mean the stalk of $\mathcal{F}$ at $p$? That would not be finite-dimensional.

Comment: I edited the final bit!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this works for a proof:

As @Sisi points out (I think) we have the following
**Lemma:** If $M$ is a finitely generated (hence noetherian) $\mathcal{O}_p$-module and let $\mathcal{M}$ denote the skyscraper sheaf $i_* M$, where $i : \{p\} \to U$.
Then $\mathcal{M}$ is a coherent $\mathcal{O}$-module if multiplication $\mathcal{O}(U) \times \mathcal{M}(U) \to \mathcal{M}(U)$ is defined by $f \cdot m = f_p m$ when $U \ni p$.
*Proof:* In a nbh $U$ of $p$ it is finitely generated by generators $m_1, \dots, m_n$ of $M$. Furthermore the kernel of the map $\mathcal{O}(U)^{\oplus n} \to \mathcal{M}(U)$ given by $(m_1, \dots, m_n)$ is a submodule of $M$ and hence finitely generated.
$\square$

Now in this example $\mathcal{F}_p$ is a finitely generated $\mathcal{O}_p$-module (by coherence of $\mathcal{F}$) and the sheaf $\mathcal{G}$ is the skyscraper associated to $M = \left\{s \in \mathcal{F}_p \,\middle\vert\, s \text{ defined on $U \in p$ and } s|_{U ∖ p} = 0 \right\}⊆ \mathcal{F}_p$.

The idea of showing finite $\mathbb{C}$-dimension seems to be a red herring as is trying to use some kind of finiteness of global sections?